# Conditional statement in while loop not executing everything under it

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, conditional-statements

Basically I'm trying to create a sort of quiz using lists. The code goes like this:

```py
foot_bones = ["calcaneus", "talus", "cuboid", "navicular", "lateral cuneiform",
             "intermediate cuneiform", "medial cuneiform"]
d = len(foot_bones)
def foot_bones_quiz():
    correct_answers = 0
    answers_left = len(foot_bones)
    guess = input("Enter a bone or q to quit: ")
    while True:        
        if guess.lower() == "q":
            break
        elif guess.lower() in foot_bones:
            print("We got a match on index ",foot_bones.index(guess.lower()))
            #Removes the previous guess from the list to ensure the user can't answer the same thing again
            foot_bones.remove(guess.lower())
            guess = ("Enter a bone or q to quit: ")
            correct_answers += 1
            answers_left -= 1
        else:
            answers_left -= 1
            guess = input("No match. Please try again. You have %s tries left. Enter q to quit"%answers_left)

        if answers_left == 0:
            break
    print("You have %s correct answers out of %s."%(correct_answers,d)

foot_bones_quiz()
```

When I enter "calcaneus", I expected the code to execute everything under the elif statement. What ends up happening is after it prints "We got a match on index blah", the "No match" thing prints which is under the else statement.

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `guess` under your `elif` should be:

```
guess = input("Enter a bone or q to quit: ")
```

Instead of:

```
guess = ("Enter a bone or q to quit: ")
```

What's going on is you've entered your first bone which causes your code to get here:

```
        print("We got a match on index ",foot_bones.index(guess.lower()))
        #Removes the previous guess from the list to ensure the user can't answer the same thing again
        foot_bones.remove(guess.lower())
        guess = ("Enter a bone or q to quit: ")
        correct_answers += 1
        answers_left -= 1
```

This block executes. Note that `guess` is set to the value `"enter a bone or q to quit: "`. You aren't asking for an input.

So now that guess is `"enter a bone or q to quit: "`, we reach the end of what's under the loop and restart it.

Since `guess.lower()` isn't in `foot_bones` and it's not `"q"` either, you end up in the `else` statement.